# How to write a regex to ignore tabs, blank lines and spaces?

Tags: java, regex, string

In this file, there are some blank lines, some tabs, and some spaces. I want to read a line every time and split this line correctly using regex according a rule. The rule asks me to ignore tabs, blank lines and spaces.
The content of txt file is shown below.

```
99999999 990001 * 01119111 55565    33333 + * +  88888888              +



123456789 1111111111 * 111119 2111111 9111111 * + *  1 ^


9 1 +     5 *     00000000 + 

999999999  0 *

9 0 ^


 5555555 333333 5454353 999999 666666 01 ^ * * +
  


 3432 3333 9999 + * ^ * * 6666 +
```

How can we write this regex to satisify all requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is for finding patterns in strings, they can't be used to perform operations, e.g. splitting. You could use a regex to recognise a newline but the implementation of that would be down to the language of the program you are writing.

In Java for example:

```
String[] splitString = yourString.split("\n");
```

Comment: Thank@Vorkos. I use String[] words = line.split("\\s+|\n"); to ignore the blank lines, but it doesn't work.

Comment: ```String[] words = line.split("\\s+\\n");```


It should be "\\" not "|\".


https://regex101.com/ is your friend.

Comment: @echo you can not use a regex to make your code ignore blank lines when you already didn’t ignore them before the `split`. The problem is to read the file line by line when you do not want to process the input as lines. Processing a file as the intended tokens can be as easy as, e.g. `try(Scanner s = new Scanner(yourFile)) { while(s.hasNext("\\S+")) { System.out.println(s.next("\\S+")); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, "anything other than tabs, blank lines, and spaces." That translates into `[^\n\t ]` and you want any combination of them `[^\n\t ]+` captured in a grouping `([^\n\t ]+)`. So the final pattern should be:

`([^\n\t ]+)`